# Launch additional executable with mac app

Tags: xcode, nstask

I am currently stuck into a problem that I think is easy, if you know how to do it. In may Mac App (Don´t worry, it´s not for the MAS, so there won´t be any problems) I need to launch a little extra executable in the backround. It´s just a deamon checking for messages when the application is closed (I lnow there are push notifications, but my customers are still on Mac OS 10.6 or earlier). I am currently trying it like this:

```
NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForAuxiliaryExecutable:@"Message_Fetcher"];
NSTask *aTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[aTask setLaunchPath:path];
[aTask launch];
```

It makes the application crash with the following message:

```
-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil value (key: _NSTaskExecutablePath)
```

What have I done wrong? Is there Any example application demonstrating it?

Thanks in advance, Jannes

Answer (score 0):

The path was nil.

```
NSString* horseBox = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Message_Fetcher" ofType:@""];
NSTask *aTask = [[NSTask alloc] init];
[aTask launch];
```

...is the solution